# Entity Framework, configuration for reading and writing

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Given the following database model

[image]

I have two fluent entity framework configurations, one that works when I read (the setupFields list is set) and the other for writing, which if I use for reading as well, always comes with an empty SetupFields list

```
[Table("[BALANCE.SETUP]")]
public class SetupEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ChassisEntity Chassis { get; set; }

    public virtual EventEntity Event { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SetupFieldEntity> SetupFields { get; set; }
}

[Table("[BALANCE.SETUP.FIELD]")]
public class SetupFieldEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid SetupId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    public string Section { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual SetupEntity Setup { get; set; }
}
```

(can read)

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<SetupEntity>()
            .HasMany(x => x.SetupFields)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Setup)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("SETUPID"));
```

(can write)

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<SetupEntity>()
            .HasMany(x => x.SetupFields)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.SetupId);
```

If I use the read configuration to read, this is the error I get:

> The column name 'SETUPID' is specified more than once in the SET clause. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same SET clause. Modify the SET clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If the SET clause updates columns of a view, then the column name 'SETUPID' may appear twice in the view definition.

**UPDATE 1**

Just to make things clear, the models are lazy loaded and I'm explicitly inclucing them, so, when using the first connfiguration the models are set as expected:

```
if (includeFields)
{
    x = x.Include(entity => entity.SetupFields);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Based on the comments bellow I change the mappings to have just this which works when inserting but when reading the child collection is still null:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SetupEntity>().HasMany(x => x.SetupFields);


[Table("[BALANCE.SETUP]")]
public class SetupEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ChassisEntity Chassis { get; set; }

    public virtual EventEntity Event { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SetupFieldEntity> SetupFields { get; set; }
}

[Table("[BALANCE.SETUP.FIELD]")]
public class SetupFieldEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid SetupId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    public string Section { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual SetupEntity Setup { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

Based on the comments I completelly removed the attributes from the entities, but the collection property is still null :(

```
public class SetupEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ChassisEntity Chassis { get; set; }

    public virtual EventEntity Event { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SetupFieldEntity> SetupFields { get; set; }
}

[Table("[BALANCE.SETUP.FIELD]")]
public class SetupFieldEntity
{
    public Guid SetupId { get; set; }

    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    public string Section { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual SetupEntity Setup { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<SetupEntity>()
    .HasKey(x => x.Id)
    .HasMany(x => x.SetupFields)
    .WithRequired(x => x.Setup);

modelBuilder.Entity<SetupFieldEntity>()
    .HasKey(x => x.SetupId)
    .HasKey(x => x.Sequence);
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Hum, I thought it would be clear. That's definitely a problem with my mappings, cause I should have only one, not two. and that is the problem.I need to enable one of them to read and the other to write. The problem seems to be related with the fact that the navigation key is also the primary key in the child table and although the design is wrong I can't add a auto number to that table.

Comment: The one that comes back blank... Are you explicitly enabling lazy loading of properties / using `.Include(Table)` ? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Yes I have that, one of the configurations works fine when reading and that collection is always set.

Comment: Seems like you're mixing the attribute based configuration _with_ the fluent configuration.  Since you decorate the properties with the `[Key]` attribute, I think the `.Map(x => x.MapKey("SETUPID"))` is redundant - maybe that's causing the problem?

Comment: @CodingGorilla even after removing those attributes the collection is still null.